# Continuous summation of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I have a simple function:

```
func =x Sin[π x]^2
```

This creates a curve that oscillates between `0` and values that increase linearly with `x`.

I want to create a continuous ***sum*** of `func`, so that incremental increases in `x` add to the running total. The result would be a continuously rising curve, with periods of rapid growth interspersed with periods of something closer to a plateau, based on the frequency of the `Sin` function.

How do I do this?

Comment: `f=Integrate[x Sin[Pi x]^2,x] ;
Plot[f,{x,0,4Pi}]`

Comment: How does a "continous summation" differ from an integral?

Comment: I went to sleep last night realising what a dumb question it was! Many thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "continuous sum" of a function is it's integral so

```
f[x_] := x Sin[Pi x]^2
sumf = Integrate[f[x], x];
Plot[{f[x], sumf}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Accumulate`

```
f[x_] := x Sin[Pi x]^2
n = 10000;
sumf = Accumulate@(2 Pi/n f@Subdivide[0., 2 Pi, n]);
Show[ListLinePlot[sumf, DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2], PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]